# How modify my CaptchaSecurityImages.php page in Latest PHP code(Functions and Class)

Tags: php

This is my **CaptchaSecurityImages.php** Page Source Code

```PHP
<?php
session_start();
class CaptchaSecurityImages {

    var $font = 'fonts/monofont.ttf';

    function generateCode($characters) {
        /* list all possible characters, similar looking characters and vowels have been removed */
        $possible = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }
    function CaptchaSecurityImages($width='120',$height='40',$characters='6') {
        $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
        /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
        $font_size = $height * 0.75;
        $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
        /* set the colours */
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 13, 213, 220);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
        $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 220, 250);
        /* generate random dots in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
        }
        /* generate random lines in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
            imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
        }
        /* create textbox and add text */
        $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
        $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
        $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
        /* output captcha image to browser */
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $_SESSION['security_code'] = $code;
    }

}

$width = isset($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '120';
$height = isset($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '40';
$characters = isset($_GET['characters']) && $_GET['characters'] > 1 ? $_GET['characters'] : '6';

$captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages($width,$height,$characters);

?>
```

This code is running perfect on older version of PHP, But new Version of PHP (Latest) is showing below mention Error:-

**Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; CaptchaSecurityImages has a deprecated constructor in CaptchaSecurityImages.php on line 3**

**Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home4/XXXXX/public_html/CaptchaSecurityImages.php:3) in CaptchaSecurityImages.php on line 2**

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/XXXXX/public_html/CaptchaSecurityImages.php:3) in CaptchaSecurityImages.php on line 42**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class constructor from `function CaptchaSecurityImages(...)` to `function __construct(...)`. This should resolve the first issue (deprecation), which should then resolve the second and third (the headers can not be modified as the error message itself has already been output by that point).

Comment: anybody can give same source code after modification in latest version of PHP. coz just now i did it as your reply but again i got same error. :-(

Comment: Now i re-check my code and then try, So now It's working.
**Thank You** so much Mr. @Sam_Judge

Comment: @HirdeshVashishtha No problem. Good luck programming!

Comment: I changed from function CaptchaSecurityImages(...) to function __construct(...), my image still broken in PHP7.2. Do I need to add public? Thanks!

Comment: @dnez it depends on what you mean by broken, honestly. If your image is corrupt then that is a separate issue to what was going on here. Default visibility of methods in php is already public.

Comment: @Sam Judge I have posted the solution of my issue below.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you should start using constructors in PHP as:

```
public function __construct(...) {
    ...
}
```

As the error tells you, your current declaration is to be deprecated soon. Same goes for destructor:

```
public function __destruct() {
    ...
}
```

The next two errors will disappear afterwards, as they show only because of error printing on screen before session initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with the same codes.

My image still broken after I have changed from CaptchaSecurityImages(...) to function __construct(...).

After searches from Google, I found out that imagettfbbox() required full path so I changed of the following codes and it fixed the broken image.

from:

```
var $font = 'fonts/monofont.ttf';
```

to:

```
var $font = __DIR__.'/fonts/monofont.ttf';
```